# compare string with startWith in scala

Tags: string, scala

I want to compare a pattern in string

```
sealed trait Demo { def value: String }

   object Demo {
  case object TypeAB extends Demo {
    val value = "a:b"
  }
      .......other constants
}
 val test = Option("a:b:c")
val s =test.map(_.startsWith(Demo.TypeAB.value))
```

I want to not use `.value` in `Demo.TypeAB.value`
Is there a better approach to achieve the above .I preferred to use `startsWith`

I tried but it didnot work

```
 def unapply(arg: Demo): String= arg.value
```

Comment: But `.value` is the underlying `String`. How else would you access it?

Comment: yes .any better way to achieve it .I thought of using startsWith , any other approach

Answer (score 1):

```
sealed trait Demo {
  def value: String
}    

object Demo {

  case object TypeAB extends Demo {
    val value = "a:b"
  }

  implicit def demoToString(demo: Demo): String = demo.value
}
```

You can now write `"a:b:c".startsWith(Demo.TypeAB)`
Whether it's a good idea to have an implicit Demo to string method in your code, well, I'll leave it up to you :D

Answer (score 0):

You could add predicates to `Demo` that provide the tests you need:

```
sealed trait Demo {
  def value: String
  def startsWith(body: Option[String]): Boolean = body match {
    case Some(content) => content.startsWith(value)
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

This allows you to hide the implementation details at the cost of a broader interface.

Answer (score 0):

Does this counts as a better way:

```
sealed trait Demo {
  def value: String

  def startsWith(s: String): Boolean = s.startsWith(value)
}

object Demo {

  case object TypeAB extends Demo {
    val value = "a:b"
  }

}

val test = Option("a:b:c")
val s = test.map(Demo.TypeAB.startsWith(_))
println(s)
```

or maybe you want to use implicits magic such as

```
sealed trait Demo {      def value: String    }

implicit class DemoStringOps(val s: String) extends AnyRef {
  def startsWith(d: Demo) = s.startsWith(d.value)
}

object Demo {

  case object TypeAB extends Demo {
    val value = "a:b"
  }

}

val test = Option("a:b:c")

val s = test.map(_.startsWith(Demo.TypeAB))
println(s)
```

Comment: yes second option better or I can simply use 
```implicit def startsWith(d: Demo) = d.value```